# Animate text within a circle - Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, animation

The following animates a circle and lines based on a given radius. I'm hoping combine the plot with animated text highlighting different segments within this circle. The text does get updated for each new frame but it doesn't remove the previous frames text.

Note: I'm trying to keep the animate function as I want to keep the axis the same and only animate updated data.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import math 

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],                        
    'X2' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0],
    'Y2' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'Angle' : [0,0,0,0,-45,-45,-45,-45,90,90,90,90],                    
    })

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,10))

grid = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gridsize = (1, 2)

ax = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 1))
ax2.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax2.set_ylim(-10, 10)

# the center of the compass
moving_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X2'].apply(list))
moving_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y2'].apply(list))
moving_point = ax.scatter(moving_x[0], moving_y[0], c = 'black', marker = 'o', zorder = 3)

radius = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2', 'Y2'])[['X2', 'Y2']].values

circle = plt.Circle(radius[0], 10, color = 'black', fill = False, lw = 0.2)
circle2 = plt.Circle(radius[0], 10, color = 'red', fill = False, lw = 0.2)

ax.add_patch(circle)
ax2.add_patch(circle2)

line1, = ax.plot([],[], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
line2, = ax.plot([],[], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)

t = df['Angle'][0]
angles = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Angle'].apply(list))

angleText = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','Angle'])['Angle'].values

rot_mat = lambda theta:np.array([
    [np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))],
    [np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))]
])

# compass tags
annotate_tags = ['N','E','S','W']

def animate(i) :

    moving_point.set_offsets(np.c_[moving_x[0+i], moving_y[0+i]])
    circle.center = (radius[i,0], radius[i,1])

    xs1L1=-10.0/2**0.5
    ys1L1=10.0/2**0.5
    xs2L1=10.0/2**0.5
    ys2L1=-10.0/2**0.5

    xs1L2=-xs1L1
    ys1L2=ys1L1
    xs2L2=-xs1L2
    ys2L2=ys2L1

    cx=radius[i,0]
    cy=radius[i,1]

    theta=math.radians(angles[i][0])

    x1L1=(  (xs1L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys1L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    x2L1=(  (xs2L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys2L1+radius[i,1]- cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    y1L1=( -(xs1L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys1L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    y2L1=( -(xs2L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys2L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy

    line1.set_data([x1L1,x2L1],[y1L1,y2L1])

    x1L2=(  (xs1L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys1L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    x2L2=(  (xs2L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys2L2+radius[i,1]- cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    y1L2=( -(xs1L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys1L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    y2L2=( -(xs2L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys2L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy

    line2.set_data([x1L2,x2L2],[y1L2,y2L2])        

    # Animate compass tags for each frame
    tag_pos = np.array([[0,8.5],[8.5,0],[0,-8.5],[-8.5,0]])    
    tag_pos = tag_pos @ rot_mat(angleText[i])

    for tag,pos in zip(annotate_tags,tag_pos):
        ax.annotate(tag,xy=pos+radius[i], xycoords='data',
                      fontsize=10,horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,3), blit = False)
```

Comment: I would suggest you create the text objects with `annotate` outside the animation function. Then you can `.set_x()` and `.set_y()` on those text objects inside your `animate` function, similar to how you use `.set_data()` for the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create text objects for as many tags outside the `animate` function. And, inside the `animate` function `set_text` and `set_position` as shown here:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import math 

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],                        
    'X2' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0],
    'Y2' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'Angle' : [0,0,0,0,-45,-45,-45,-45,90,90,90,90],                    
    })

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))

grid = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gridsize = (1, 2)

ax = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 1))
ax2.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax2.set_ylim(-10, 10)

# the center of the compass
moving_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X2'].apply(list))
moving_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y2'].apply(list))
moving_point = ax.scatter(moving_x[0], moving_y[0], c = 'black', marker = 'o', zorder = 3)

radius = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2', 'Y2'])[['X2', 'Y2']].values

circle = plt.Circle(radius[0], 10, color = 'black', fill = False, lw = 0.2)
circle2 = plt.Circle(radius[0], 10, color = 'red', fill = False, lw = 0.2)

ax.add_patch(circle)
ax2.add_patch(circle2)

line1, = ax.plot([],[], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
line2, = ax.plot([],[], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)

t = df['Angle'][0]
angles = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Angle'].apply(list))

angleText = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','Angle'])['Angle'].values

rot_mat = lambda theta:np.array([
    [np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))],
    [np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))]
])

# compass tags
annotate_tags = ['N','E','S','W']
annotation=[None]*len(annotate_tags)
for i in range(len(annotate_tags)):
    annotation[i] = ax.annotate('', xy=(0, 0),xycoords='data',fontsize=10,horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')


def animate(i) :

    moving_point.set_offsets(np.c_[moving_x[0+i], moving_y[0+i]])
    circle.center = (radius[i,0], radius[i,1])

    xs1L1=-10.0/2**0.5
    ys1L1=10.0/2**0.5
    xs2L1=10.0/2**0.5
    ys2L1=-10.0/2**0.5

    xs1L2=-xs1L1
    ys1L2=ys1L1
    xs2L2=-xs1L2
    ys2L2=ys2L1

    cx=radius[i,0]
    cy=radius[i,1]

    theta=math.radians(angles[i][0])

    x1L1=(  (xs1L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys1L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    x2L1=(  (xs2L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys2L1+radius[i,1]- cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    y1L1=( -(xs1L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys1L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    y2L1=( -(xs2L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys2L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy

    line1.set_data([x1L1,x2L1],[y1L1,y2L1])

    x1L2=(  (xs1L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys1L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    x2L2=(  (xs2L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys2L2+radius[i,1]- cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    y1L2=( -(xs1L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys1L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    y2L2=( -(xs2L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys2L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy

    line2.set_data([x1L2,x2L2],[y1L2,y2L2])        

    # Animate compass tags for each frame
    tag_pos = np.array([[0,8.5],[8.5,0],[0,-8.5],[-8.5,0]])    
    tag_pos = tag_pos @ rot_mat(angleText[i])
    k=0
    for tag,pos in zip(annotate_tags,tag_pos):
        annotation[k].set_text(tag)
        annotation[k].set_position(xy=pos+radius[i])
        k=k+1

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,3), blit = False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=5)
plt.show()
```